# PHP File upload script getting in the way

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload

I have this form

[image]

If the first radio button is clicked, the textfield below it is enabled and if the 2nd radio button is clicked, the file upload is enabled and the former is disabled,vice versa. It works fine if the file upload option is chosen but if the 1st radio button is chosen and the file upload is disabled, it doesn't insert data in the database. :/ What should be done to successfully send the form details even if the file upload is disabled/empty?

CODE:

```
 <form name="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table width="416" height="245" border="1" align="center">
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2">Transaction No: <input type="text" name="transaction_no" id="transaction_no" /> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center">Please select the mode of payment</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td width="183" align="center"><input name="rad" type="radio" onclick="enableField(this)" value="Smart Money" checked="checked"> 
   Smart Money</td>
   <td width="201" align="center"><input name="rad" type="radio" onclick="enableField(this)" value="BPI"> BPI Bank Deposit</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td align="center"><input type="text" name="contactno" id="contactno"></td>
   <td align="center"><input name="filename" type="file" id="filename" disabled="disabled"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Total amount sent:</td>
   <td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="totalsent" id="totalsent" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Date sent:</td>
   <td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="datesent" id="datesent" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form" />

   </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['filename'])){
$errors = array();
$file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$file_size =$_FILES['filename']['size'];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$file_type=$_FILES['filename']['type'];   
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['filename']['name'])));


$expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
    $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
}
if($file_size > 2097152){
 $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
}          

// pag walang error...     
if (empty($errors)==true) {

    // upload the file...
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = " ";
    $dbname = "admin";

    // create new record in the database
   include ("dbinfo.php");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO payment_form (date, Tracking, mode, ContactNo, totalsent, datesent, filename) VALUES (NOW(), '$transactionNo', '$rad', '$contactNo', '$totalSent', '$dateSent', '$file_name')") ;

   header('Location: paymentform_success.php');
}else{
    print_r($errors);
}
}

?>
```

Javascript for enable/disable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enableField(obj){
var form=obj.form;
var txtNames=['contactno','filename'], f;
var rads=document.getElementsByName(obj.name), r, i=0;
while(r=rads[i++]){
f=form[txtNames[i-1]];
if(r.checked){
    f.removeAttribute('disabled');
    f.focus();
}
else{
    f.value='';
    f.setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great to see the security practices in place here!

Answer (score 0):

You should first check which radio is checked and then decide what to do. It's not working because the whole script is under the `if(isset($_FILES['filename']))`. If the file upload is disabled then `$_FILES` will not be set and nothing will be executed.

Comment: I don't have time to write it fully, but I'd do something like this: http://pastebin.com/9jWxpHj6

Comment: @MarkTu before you do anything else you might want to read about sql-injections and why your code is vulnerable.

Comment: @Phate01 Hi i'm testing it out. can you give me an example for the //Actions part in the if else?sorry i'm kinda new.

Comment: I'm reading the query now, and I see that it contains both filename and contactno. But how is that possible if you're surely getting just one of them?

Comment: @Phate01 yeah that was the initial query in the question.hmm. because I have a table that contains those fields. If a contactno was entered the file upload should insert at least empty string in the db,and vice versa. do you have know ho to do that..I'm kinda lost. Or javascript if it's easier. anyway my main problem is as stated in the question. T__T

Comment: @Phate01 have you figured it out sir?

Comment: I made you the whole script, although I didn't test it: http://pastebin.com/XUuLsyTn

Comment: The key idea is that you take all fields of the form that don't depend on the rad button. Then you will check the rad value and depending on it you'll set `$contact_no` or `$file_name` empty. Then, when you finished controlling the form, you'll perform the query.